# bottom menu hiding/showing on scroll up and down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code which hides my menu when scrolls down, shows when scrolls up.

js

```
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('nav').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
 if (didScroll) {
   hasScrolled();
   didScroll = false;
 }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;
  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight ) {
    // Scroll Down
  $('nav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
  } else {
    // Scroll Up
    if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    }
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

I would like it to hide and reveal in the same way but both scrolling up and down (it hides when you scroll either up or down then comes back down)

Comment: This may need a fiddle, example or diagram showing what you're trying to accomplish. Currently, it's a little bit unclear what the end goal is.

Comment: This is working code like the example provided below at http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/ but I want it to animate away after the user scrolls in either direction. then comes back down when they stop scrolling